# ContentType.FieldLinks.Add() issue with hidden and required

Tags: development, content-type, feature, site-column, spfield

I have a feature that does the following in the **feature activation Code** :

- Creates a new SiteColumn (**Type=Text**, **Hidden=False** and **Required =True**)
- Set the french version of the Name (using CurrentUICulture switching)
- Create a new ContentType
- Add the SiteColumn to the new Content Type
- Create a new list
- Attach the ContentType to the list

But that causes some unexpected behaviors.

Sometimes my Column in the list is Hidden=True, sometimes Required=False.  It seems to be totally Random.

It seems related to the ContentType.FieldLinks.Add() since the values are wrong in the content type.

Anyone faced something like that before?

Thanks

Comment: Try to set values in **upper** case - `Hidden="FALSE"` and `Required="TRUE"`

Comment: I may have been unclear.  That is done through code and those properties are boolean, I cannot set String values there. sorry.

Comment: Did you finally found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I did not find any way to resolve the issue (or at least I don't remember how I fixed it) sorry.

Answer (score 1):

- Have you made the list content type enabled - SPList.ContentTypeEnabled?
- Try to set the 'Required' property on the fieldlink from the content type and not directly on the site column itself
- You don't have to set the 'Hidden' property, it's false by default.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer on a similar question that I think is the same root cause:

[Random Hidden Fields On New Content Type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71270/random-hidden-fields-on-new-content-type/71301#71301)