# Random Hidden Fields On New Content Type

Tags: content-type

I have the following code used to programmatically create content types.  The code creates and deletes the content type using a windows form app which I will eventually transfer to an event receiver.  The odd thing is that with each time I delete/create the content type random fields are marked as hidden.  To compensate I even added false to the Hidden property on the SPField but to no avail.  Has anyone seen this oddity before?  Suggestions for fixing are welcome.  Thanks for reading.

```
#region Field Defs
var passprtFieldName = web.Fields.Add("Passport Number", SPFieldType.Text, false);
var passprtField = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(passprtFieldName) as SPFieldText;
passprtField.MaxLength = 15;
passprtField.Group = GROUP_NAME;
passprtField.AllowDeletion = false;
passprtField.Hidden = false;
passprtField.Update();

var empIdFieldName = web.Fields.Add("Employee ID", SPFieldType.Text, false);
var empIdField = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(empIdFieldName) as SPFieldText;
empIdField.MaxLength = 10;
empIdField.Group = GROUP_NAME;
empIdField.AllowDeletion = false;
empIdField.Hidden = false;
empIdField.Update();

....

var item = web.ContentTypes["Item"];
var volunteers = new SPContentType(item, web.ContentTypes, VOLUNTEER_CONTENT_TYPE_NAME);
volunteers.Group = GROUP_NAME;

var title = volunteers.FieldLinks["Title"] as SPFieldLink;
title.DisplayName = "Volunteer Name";

volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(passprtField));
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(empIdField));
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(driveLicField));
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(homeStreetAddrsField));
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(homeCityAddrsField));
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(homeStateAddrsField));
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(homeZipAddrsField));

web.ContentTypes.Add(volunteers);
volunteers.Update();
```

*Results for run 1*
[image]

*Results for run 2*
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this problem on 2010 and 2013 :) I have run into lots of quirks like this before, and I believe it is because the object in memory does not reflect the correct state of the object after you call Update(), and then you try to use the same in-memory object for another purpose. In the past I have found it necessary to discard a new SharePoint object after Update() and re-create before using it later.

e.g from your code...

```
// here you create and then update the field object
var passprtFieldName = web.Fields.Add("Passport Number", SPFieldType.Text, false);
var passprtField = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(passprtFieldName) as SPFieldText;
passprtField.MaxLength = 15;
passprtField.Group = GROUP_NAME;
passprtField.AllowDeletion = false;
passprtField.Hidden = false;
passprtField.Update();
...
// later you use the same object to add as a Field Link on the Content Type
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(passprtField);
```

I was able to fix the problem two ways. When adding the field link, set the Hidden and ReadOnly properties on the new SPFieldLink object:

```
SPFieldLink passprtFieldLink = new SPFieldLink(passprtField);
passprtFieldLink.Hidden = false;
passprtFieldLink.Required = false;
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(passprtFieldLink);
```

but I believe this is just masking the problem. The better approach is to re-retrieve a new SPField object:

```
// refresh the object by retrieving an updated reference before adding as field link   
SPField passprtField = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(passprtField.InternalName);
volunteers.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(passprtField));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That did it!  I used your second approach and all came out clean.  Thanks Chris!